# NIFI:Configuring Cron scheduling

Tags: cron, apache-nifi

I want to use cron scheduling in invokehttp and generateflowfile  processors and I use expression like this `* 57 12 1/1 * ? *` ti start  working at this time but what I see is that invokehttp processor starts  work at 12:57 minutes and processing only those flowfiles which are in flowfile queue as a result it doesn't process flowfiles which are generated after 12:57 . what should I do to force  it work it as usual (I mean processing all flowfiles after 12:57 too)?

Comment: just remove cron on invokehttp

Comment: unfortanetely i need  cron too